# Can i store a stream analytics job (located: South Middle US) in a different located SQL DB (located: West Europe)?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

i'm doing the polar bear training module (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/learn/modules/build-ml-model-with-azure-stream-analytics/11-connect-db-and-function) from MS.

I have a MSDN Subs, in this case i can't create a DB in the same location like my other Resources.

In the 11th Step in the tutorial i connected my DB with the job, but i don't get any results in my DB after running the job for 5 min. (

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but you would incur costs to transfer data between regions